# Is there an issue with adding contact details to native app from iOS?

Tags: ios, contacts

We are at the end of our rope with this one.  It's been months and we have no idea what the issue is.

We have a low frequency, intermittent bug on our iOS app where adding information to our app from iPhone contacts causes the app to crash.

Is there a known issue with accessing iPhone contacts?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?  Feel free to obfuscate any proprietary details

Comment: I actually do not.  We are working on getting our reporting sorted out.

Comment: Ok, in the absence of a stack trace, I would recommend that you set up some unit tests that provide your essential methods with invalid or unexpected data.  For example, let's say you have a method for handling an array of contacts provided by Apple.  What happens if you pass in a `nil` array?  How about if you pass in an `NSString` or `NSError` instead of the expected type?  You're most likely dealing with an uncaught exception if you're using ARC.  If you're using manual reference counting, you might want to explore the possibility of an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS`.